# Dijkstra´s algorithm own implementation problem

Tags: java, graph-theory, dijkstra

I have inside a simple Graph class this Dijkstra Algorithm O(n^2) implementation and when debugging it the output is different than the expected one from the JUnit Test and I cannot find the problem:

```
    public void Dijkstra(T departureNode) {
    initDijkstra(departureNode);

    ArrayList<GraphNode<T>> V_S = fillWithoutElement(departureNode);

    while (V_S.size() > 0) {
        int w  = chooseMinimum(D);
        nodes.get(w).setVisited(true);
        GraphNode<T> auxW = nodes.get(w);
        V_S.remove(findOnV_S(V_S, auxW));

        for(GraphNode<T> m : V_S) {
            if (D[w] + weights[w][getNode(m.getElement())] < D[getNode(m.getElement())]) {
                D[getNode(m.getElement())] = D[w] + weights[w][getNode(m.getElement())];
                PD[getNode(m.getElement())] = w;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the auxiliary method chooseMinimum():

```
    private int chooseMinimum(double[] auxD) {
    int res = 0;
    double min = INFINITE;
    for (int i = 0; i < auxD.length; i++) {
        if (!nodes.get(i).isVisited()) {
            if (auxD[i] < min) {
                min = auxD[i];
                res = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

And this is the findOnV_S() method:

```
    private int findOnV_S(ArrayList<GraphNode<T>> V_S, GraphNode<T> auxW) {
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < V_S.size(); i++) {
        if(V_S.get(i).equals(auxW))
            res = i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This is the initDijkstra() method:

```
public void initDijkstra(T departureNode) {
    if (!itExists(departureNode))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node does not exist");

    D = new double[size];
    PD = new int[size];
    int j = getNode(departureNode);
    // Initialize D
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (edges[j][i]) {
            D[i] = weights[j][i];
        } else
            D[i] = INFINITE;
    }

    // Initialize PD
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (edges[j][i])
            PD[i] = getNode(departureNode);
        else
            PD[i] = EMPTY;
    }

    initializeVisitedToFalseExceptStart(departureNode);
}
```

And this is the initializeVisitedToFalseExceptStart aux method:

```
    private void initializeVisitedToFalseExceptStart(T departureNode) {
    if (!itExists(departureNode))
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid node");
    GraphNode<T> element = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        element = nodes.get(i);
        if ((element.getElement()).equals(departureNode))
            element.setVisited(true);
        else
            nodes.get(i).setVisited(false);
    }
}
```

PD: I think that the wrong method is chooseMinimum()

PD2: In the next JUnit you will see that getD() will return a 2 dimensional array but the actual D inside the Graph class is a unidimensional array.

PD3: This is the simple JUnit test:

```
     try
     {
         g.addNode("V1");
         g.addNode("V2");
         g.addNode("V3");
         g.addNode("V4");
         g.addNode("V5");
         g.addNode("V6");
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println ("No repeated nodes are allowed" + e);
     }

     try
     {
         g.addEdge ("V1", "V2", 3.0);
         g.addEdge ("V1", "V3", 4.0);
         g.addEdge ("V1", "V5", 8.0);

         g.addEdge ("V2", "V5", 5.0);

         g.addEdge ("V3", "V5", 3.0);

         g.addEdge ("V5", "V6", 3.0);
         g.addEdge ("V5", "V4", 7.0);

         g.addEdge ("V6", "V4", 2.0);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println ("Starting or arrival node does not exists" + e);
     }

     g.Dijkstra ("V1");
     assertArrayEquals (new double[][]{{Graph.INFINITE, 3.0, 4.0, 12.0, 7.0, 10.0}}, g.getD());
     assertArrayEquals (new int[]{-1, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4}, g.getPD());
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you are initializing the algorithm distances? Also, I think in your chooseMinimum method you are using D in the for loop instead of auxD

Comment: @mettleap already made the changes you said

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. You have this method called initializeVisitedToFalseExceptStart(departureNode)
inside your initDijkstra method. So when the initial call to chooseMinimum is done in the while loop, you are finding the minimum without considering the departureNode

I think if you will remove that method call inside the initDijkstra method, your algorithm will run fine.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but It didn´t work, the final state of D and PD is the same as before

Comment: Could you print w in your run and share that here?

Comment: `W:
1
2
3
4
5
`
`D: Infinity, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, `
`PD: -1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, `

Comment: @Angelixus, Ok, found another issue. You are initializing V_S without the departureNode first and then in the while loop you are trying to remove it from V_S. This may be removing some other node that you didn’t intend to remove

Comment: would you mind to write some sample code of what you mean, i tried to initialize V_S with the departureNode but the problem persists. Moreover, I tried to remove from V_S after the for-each loop.

Comment: This is the pseudocode I based my code on: http://www.gitta.info/Accessibiliti/en/html/Dijkstra_learningObject1.html